# Association! Why So Nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm trying to associate these models on ***create bar action.***

I know that both bar and type are nil objects that are not created yet, but why, the ruby don't understand that all that i want is just tie these nil objects?

So, i searched for the answers, but none of them explained clearly why this error: **Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id**

happen in this situation.

**User - Model**

```
has_one :bar
```

**Bar - Model**

```
belongs_to :type
belongs_to :user
```

**Type - Model**

```
has_many :bars
```

**Bar - Controller**

```
  def new
      @bar = Bar.new
    end

    def create
      @bar = current_user.build_bar(params[:bar].merge(:type_id => @type.id))
           if  @bar.save     
           flash.now[:success] = "Wohoo!"
             redirect_to @bar
            else
             render  :new 
           end
         end
```

**New_bar - View**

```
<div class="block">

        <%= render 'shared/flash_messages' %>

        <%= form_for @bar, :url =>  bars_path, :method => :post  do |b| %>
    <ul>
    <li><%= b.label :name %><%= b.text_field :name %></li>

    <%= b.fields_for :type  do |t| %>

    <li>pirate:<%= t.radio_button :style, "pirate" %></li>
    <li>pub:<%= t.radio_button :style, "pub" %></li>
    <li>american:<%= t.radio_button :style, "american" %></li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>

    <%= b.submit "create", :class => "sec button" %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: BTW you probably don't want to use "type" as a model name.  See, e.g. http://juicebar.wordpress.com/2007/05/30/reserved-words-in-rails/

Comment: woow! I never imagined this, the rails full of hidden tricks huh!

Answer (score 1):

Try building your `bar` object like this:

```
@bar = current_user.bar.new params[:bar].merge(:type_id => @type.id)
```

Make sure you have both a `current_user` object and a `@type` object when you call that line.

For the record, the only difference between `current_user.bar.new` and `current_user.bar.build` is that `build` adds the newly created `bar` object to the user's collection before saving it (where as `new` won't add the object to the user until it's actually saved).

Comment: Change your call to `@bar.save!` (with the exclamation mark) and then append your original post with the error being output in your logs (likely in `log/development.log`. I need to know which `id` it's looking for.

Comment: here go! Started POST "/bars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-10 20:28:37 -0300
Processing by BarsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fLI8ffLhMXWklCy7CMZWBxIvqfbBKi6Al5vo269FyYM=", "bar"=>{"name"=>"sssss", "type"=>{"style"=>"Pub"}}, "commit"=>"Create"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'pwXhuBLyjau1OEdaTxKuvw' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBar Load (13.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."user_id" = 11 LIMIT 1[0m

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

RuntimeError (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
  app/controllers/bars_controller.rb:17:in `create'

Comment: if i use Object_id create but don't associate, that's why this nil seems a nilness!

Comment: Your problem lies in this line: `"bar"=>{"name"=>"sssss", "type"=>{"style"=>"Pub"}}`. You're setting `:type_id => @type.id`, but your `type` param doesn't have an `id`.

Comment: hummm! that`s true, i fixed it, but the nil problem persists, in any case,thank you very much man! i think now this become more clear :)

Comment: You really should change the model name before doing anything else.  Using 'type' as a model name (or a column name) could be causing hard to track down problems.